# Showing the sum of all price text box(`class=price`) in to subTotal textbox(`id=subTotal`)

Tags: jquery

I am having following html table structure

```
<tr class="row" id="item10">
 <td><input type="text" name="barcode" class="barcode" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="type" class="type" readonly="true" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="color" class="color" readonly="true" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="qty" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="unitprice" readonly="true"  class="unitPrice" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="price" class="price" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 </tr>



<tr  id="SubTotal">
     <td colspan="5">SubTotal</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subTotal" id="subTotal" style="width: 50px"/></td>
  </tr>
    <tr  id="VAt">
        <td colspan="5">Vat</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="vat" id="vat" style="width: 50px"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr  id="Total">
          <td colspan="5">Total</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Total" id="Total" style="width: 50px"/></td>
     </tr>
```

There may be an no of `<tr class="row">`(generated dynamically) each table row is identified by its id
`itemXX` XX is number.

Here I reading barcode of product then its detail is filled in appropriate text boxes. 
Then when I changes the quantity of product its corresponding price is updated in text box with `class="price"'.

**My question** is when any products price is changed or entered in price text box.
The sum of all products price should be shown in subTotal text box.

Comment: there are multiple elements with id `SubTotal`

Comment: No only one `subTotal` is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var $inputs = $('input[name=price]');
$inputs.change(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $inputs.each(function () { 
        sum += +$(this).val() || 0; 
    });
    $('#subTotal').val(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('table').on('change', '.row input[name="price"]', function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.row input[name="price"]').each(function () {
        total += parseFloat(this.value)
    });
    $('#subTotal').val(total);
})
```

if the value of the `price` field is changed by a script then trigger the change event also like

```
.val(x).change()
```

Comment: It is working when I am changing any value in `price`, But i want when value should be populated(using json) in price it should show the result in `subTotal'

Answer (score 0):

Attach Jquery $table.on('change', 'td.price', function ...) to detect the change in each price  field and then within the callback function use a $.each on 'td.price' to sum

Answer (score -1):

You can get the sum by using the following code i provided, But make sure that you have to wrap the following code inside a `function` and call it possibly, in all situation(In `blur,change` events etc. Basically `textbox's` change event occurs when it lose `focus`.) when price text box changes.

```
var xSubTotal = 0;

$("tr.row input[name='price']").each(function(){
 xSubTotal += $(this).val();
});

$("#subTotal").val(xSubTotal);
```

Comment: @Bala Phone, whatsapp, etc.. are dead???  what's the purpose of having a smart phone in your hand??

Comment: @Bala Oh.. Sorry da i put the phone in charger. I didn't notice your call. Please forgive me.

Comment: @Bala People are saying that you have lot of time to complete the bond, then why are you urging me to send the resume quickly.. I thought you have built a perfect resume than mine on your own. Are you having any plans to sign off the bonds like other retards??

Comment: poda pani ... i need some experience , tat s i asking u ... i ll kill uuuuuu

Comment: @Bala Resumes are like growing a horse for your upcoming race. You have to take care of it and craft it according your own ups and downs. It should be very unique in the market. I know you have a unique way of thinking than others, but i wonder why are you hesitating to build a new one on your own? I know you are capable of using imagination to the peak. Then why can't you use it to build a better CV than others???

Comment: I dont  want any explanation ..... give or not ? ....k stop everything .............